# XSD validation issue when doing xmlbulkload into sql server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xsd, xsd-validation, bulk-load

I'm using vbscript to perform an XMLBulkLoad into SQL Server 2008.
My upload is triggered by the following:

```
objBL.execute "schedules.xsd", "scheduletest.xml"
```

This is triggering correctly. However, when I try to upload with my schema as is, I get the error:

> XML SAX Parser: Data mapping to column 'ActivityID' was already found in the data. Make sure that no two schema definitions map to the same column.

Data goes in if I change the schema to use the `<xs:choice>` tags, but then anything within those tags does not go into the table and only two rows are generated with no ActivityIDs, no Start and no End - all are NULL.

I need anything within those tags to generate a new row in the database, with the same values as before it. So with my current test xml, it would generate:

```
booking-date,           employee-id,    level,  planning-unit-id,   activity-id,    time-end,               time-start,
2015-05-02 00:00:00,    1345,           8000,   1001,               2,              2015-05-02 20:30:00,    2015-05-02 13:00:00
2015-05-02 00:00:00,    1345,           8000,   1001,               1053,           2015-05-02 12:00:00,    2015-05-02 07:00:00
2015-05-01 00:00:00,    1350,           8000,   1001,               1053,           2015-05-01 11:00:00,    2015-05-01 07:00:00
```

I think I need to alter my XSD to allow this, but I simply can't see how. Any suggestions?

My XSD is:

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
  <xs:element name="schedules" sql:is-constant="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="schedule" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" sql:relation="Merge_Schedule">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="booking-date"  sql:field="bookingdate" sql:datatype="dateTime"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="employee-id" sql:field="EmployeeID" sql:datatype="int"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="level" sql:field="LevelID" sql:datatype="int"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="planning-unit-id" sql:field="PlanningUnitID" sql:datatype="int"/>
              <xs:element name="schedule-blocks" sql:is-constant="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="schedule-block" sql:is-constant="true">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                     <!--   <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"> -->
                          <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="activity-id" sql:field="ActivityID" sql:datatype="int"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="time-end" sql:field="finish" sql:datatype="dateTime"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="time-start" sql:field="start" sql:datatype="dateTime"/>
                     <!--   </xs:choice> -->
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schedules type="array">
    <schedule>
        <booking-date type="date">2015-05-02 00:00:00</booking-date>
        <employee-id type="integer">1345</employee-id>
        <level type="integer">8000</level>
        <planning-unit-id type="integer">1001</planning-unit-id>
        <schedule-blocks type="array">
            <schedule-block>
                <activity-id>2</activity-id>
                <time-end>2015-05-02 20:30:00</time-end>
                <time-start>2015-05-02 13:00:00</time-start>
            </schedule-block>
            <schedule-block>
                <activity-id>1053</activity-id>
                <time-end>2015-05-02 12:00:00</time-end>
                <time-start>2015-05-02 07:00:00</time-start>
            </schedule-block>
        </schedule-blocks>
    </schedule>
    <schedule>
        <booking-date type="date">2015-05-01 00:00:00</booking-date>
        <employee-id type="integer">1350</employee-id>
        <level type="integer">8000</level>
        <planning-unit-id type="integer">1001</planning-unit-id>
        <schedule-blocks type="array">
            <schedule-block>
                <activity-id>1053</activity-id>
                <time-end>2015-05-01 11:00:00</time-end>
                <time-start>2015-05-01 07:00:00</time-start>
            </schedule-block>
        </schedule-blocks>
    </schedule>
</schedules>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I found to this was to transform the XML into a more manageable file for the bulk upload.